# news for nose meaning

Tags: meaning, expressions, vocabulary

I had heard the expression "have a nose for news" but when I was watching a tv show (web of lies) the expression was "news for nose". The exact quote goes like this:

> GEORGE WEBER NOT ONLY HAD **A GREAT NEWS FOR NOSE** -- A GREAT SCHNOZ AS
>   WE WOULD CALL IT -- BUT HE ALSO GOT INTO THE FABRIC OF THE VERY PEOPLE
>   WHO WERE LISTENING.

Does this mean he had a great nose for news, are they the same thing? If not, why is the difference?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  Probably should be "a great nose for news".

Comment: I thought the same thing but I watched the show, it's just what he says.

Comment: Does the character in question have a big old nose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the character misspoke, whether intentionally or not.  The phrase is really meaningless when spoken backwards like that.  I think the editors just missed it before the show aired.